# Debug Assertion Failed CDialog

Tags: c++

I have an error in my c++ project. If I clicked "Cancel" or "OK" or "X" buttons program is crashing and display an error like the screenshot. 
What could be problem? Here is full code ; http://pastebin.com/54DfqrDb

[image]

```
void CSettingDlg::OnBnClickedCancel()
{
    CDialog::OnCancel();
}

void CSettingDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    CDialog::OnOK();
}
```

Comment: Publish the entire code of your dialog class. Your stack is probably corrupted somewhere else.

Comment: Also generally you should not have custom OK and Cancel handlers as you have virtual functions `OnOK()` and `OnCancel()` that you should override in your dialog class.

Comment: Where did you use your dialog? In InitInstance or somewhere else?

Comment: This code is 476 row, how can publish it? Tell me a way for publish it please. @Mykola BOOL CSettingDlg::OnInitDialog(){CDialog::OnInitDialog();}

Comment: As you did in qestion copy & paste

Comment: And you should only post the method wich uses that dialog

Comment: Here is published http://pastebin.com/54DfqrDb

Comment: also post the method wich creates dialog and call DoModal()

Comment: I suppose you did not use modal dialogs?

Comment: yeap I used modal dialogs and this dialog is a modal.

Comment: could you please post the code wich creates and shows your dialog (not dialog class)

Comment: here -> http://pastebin.com/cu9G5vmU

Comment: Not successfull architecture was selected. Its hard to delerminate were the error occures.

Comment: Impressive internationalisation failure in this dialog.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem. If I declare already don't working a class variable this problem is occurred.

Solution :

```
//CZipArchive       m_ZipArchive; //this class variable is don't working for me
```